# Setting background gradient with jquery - jshint error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jshint

I'm trying to animate a background gradient with jQuery, like this:

```
this.$next.css('line-indent', 0).animate({
    'line-indent': 100
}, {
    "duration": 750,
    "step": function(value) {
        $(this).css({
            "background": color,
            "background": "moz-radial-gradient (50% 50%, ellipse cover, transparent " + value + "%, " + color + " " + value + "%))",
            "background": "-webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent " + value + "%, " + color + " " + value + "%)",
            "background": "radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent " + value + "%, " + color + " " + value + "%)"
        })
    },
    "easing": 'easeInQuint',
    "complete": function() {
        $(this).css({
            "transition": 'none',
            "background": color,
            "background": "moz-radial-gradient (50% 50%, ellipse cover, transparent 0%, " + color + " 0%)",
            "background": "-webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent 0%, " + color + " 0%)",
            "background": "radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 0%, " + color + " 0%)",
            "width": 0
        })
        self.$loader.fadeIn(0);
    }
});
```

This works exactly the way I want, except, when I try to build the dist files for production, jshint throws a `duplicate key` error for the `background` property, which makes sense. my question is, how to I prevent this error while setting the background gradient for all the different browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsHint is correct as your code is flawed. You're overwriting the `background` key each time you define it in the object, so only the final value will be assigned. I can only assume it works for you as `radial-gradient` works in the browser you test with.

Here's a demo of the problem you have:

```js
var foo = function(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key); // note only 1 key is shown as it's overwritten
    })
    
    console.log(o.background); // shows the last value
}

foo({
    "background": 'red',
    "background": "moz-radial-gradient (50% 50%, ellipse cover, transparent 100%, red 5%))",
    "background": "-webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent 100%, red 5%)",
    "background": "radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent 100%, red 5%)"
})
```

To fix this you need to call `attr()` and apply the style directly to the element. `css()` can't be used as it will also overwrite the `background` property each time you call it.

```
var style = [
    "background: " + color,
    "background: moz-radial-gradient (50% 50%, ellipse cover, transparent " + value + "%, " + color + " " + value + "%))",
    "background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent " + value + "%, " + color + " " + value + "%)",
    "background: radial-gradient(circle at center, transparent " + value + "%, " + color + " " + value + "%)"
].join(';');

$(this).attr('style', style);
```

I admit it's ugly, but there's no real alternative